# How do I make Heroku use my "acctest" maven profile?

Tags: maven, deployment, heroku, maven-profiles

I would like to use Heroku as an (end-user) acceptance test environment. The differences between my different environments are captured by using different maven profiles (which basically switch to use a specific directory containing the property files).

So, for local development we run "mvn -P local-dev package"; when deploying to production we run "mvn -P prod install" etc.

Now we want Heroku to run maven using the "acc-test" profile. I e, instead of running the standard "mvn install", we want a git push to trigger a "mvn -P acc-test install".

Is that possible? How can we do that?

Comment: What about a continious integration solution like Jenkins to do such things ? May in combination with Gerrit.